# JQuery image rollover using nameProp doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, dom

I have a JQuery function that converts thumbnail images to a larger image when the cursor hovers over the smaller images. This is working fine in IE but not at all in Firefox and Chrome. I am new to JQuery. Is there anything related to "nameProp" that should be different? My function is below. Thank You.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#thumbs img").mouseover(function(){
                var objthis = $(this)[0];
                document.getElementById("picture").src=objthis.nameProp;
            });
        });
```

Comment: `s$(document).ready(function(){` .. is the `s` in the beginning a mistake you made in your post here, or is it actually in the code? Also, you don't need to access any subvalues in `$(this)` when you're in an event handler. `$(this)` will refer to the current element (in your case, this is the `img` element).

Comment: The "s" is a post typo...sorry. Do you mean that I do not need "img" or "[0]"? It appears that I need those elements. I have tried without each one and no go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[nameProp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a proprietory extension that is available only in IE, use `src` attribute value instead.

```
document.getElementById("picture").src = this.getAttribute('src');
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("picture").src = $(this).attr('src');
```

*Also note that inside the mouseover handler `this` already represents the element you need to work on so you don't need to do `var objthis = $(this)[0];`*

Comment: I used the first one. Thank you very much! I did happen to notice that I did not see "nameProp" in the Firefox debugger. But don't know enough JQuery yet to go around it. Thanks again! This works in all 3 browsers.